# Parsing using Simple Xml Parser in android

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing

I am getting trouble while using web services. I want to parse the data using `simple xml parser`.If anyone have used this simple xml parser then please help.
Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a parser and send your URL from the main activity.

```
public class GoogleXmlParser {
    private static final String ns=null;

    public List<Entry>parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    { 
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser=Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in,null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return reedFeed(parser);
        }finally{
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private List<Entry>reedFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    { 
        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");
        //String name1=parser.getName();
        System.out.println(parser.getName());
        //String tag=;
        while (parser.nextTag()!=XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

            if(parser.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                continue;
            }
            String name=parser.getName();

            if(name.equals("channel")){
                String tag=parser.getName();
                System.out.println("tag"+tag);
            }
            else if(name.equals("item")){
                System.out.println("tag"+parser.getName());
                entries.add(readEntry(parser));
            }else{
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return entries;
    }

    public static class Entry
    {
        public String title=null;
        public String link=null;
        public String description=null;
        private Entry(String title, String description, String link) {
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.link = link;
        }
    }
    private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
        System.out.println(parser.getDepth());
        String title = null;
        String description = null;
        String link = null;
        while (parser.next()!=XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if(parser.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                continue;
            }
            String name=parser.getName();
            if(name.equals("title")){
                 title = readTitle(parser);
            }else if (name.equals("link")) {
                 link = readLink(parser);
            }else if(name.equals("description")){
                description = readSummary(parser);
            }else{
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new Entry(title, description, link);
    }
    private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser)throws IOException,XmlPullParserException
    {
        //parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
        //parser.next();
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
        return title;
    }
    private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser)throws IOException,XmlPullParserException
    {
        String link="";
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");
        link=parser.nextText();
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
        return link;

    }
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
    private String readSummary(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "description");
        String summary = readText(parser);
        //System.out.println(summary);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "description");
        return summary;
    }
    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the parser class call this class in main activity .let me know if you facing any problem

Answer (score 0):

Using pull parser directly is error-prone and hard since the API is very low level. Please try https://gitlab.com/mvysny/konsume-xml